# hasClass('disabled') not working after .addClass('disabled')

Tags: javascript, jquery

With selected the hasClass validation works correctly.

```
<div class="row dis">
    <input class="contact button selected" value="Contact Us">
</div>
```

---

However if i remove the selected through jquery:

```
<div class="row dis">
    <input class="contact button" value="Contact Us">
</div>
```

---

```
if (!$('.dis > .contact').hasClass('disabled')) {
    $("input.contact").click(function() {

        alert('---');
        $('.contact').addClass('disabled');

    });
}
```

the hasClass still not find the disabled class after `$('.contact').addClass('disabled');`.

So, i only want the first alert.

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/dWGNJ/2/

Comment: `$('.dis > .contact').hasClass('disabled')` returns the matching elements *right then*. It will not automatically bind to new elements as they have a class added. You can either bind to "all" `.dis > .contact` (and check the class in the handler) and/or, perhaps better, use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: You need to use event delegation with `.on()` if you're binding to classes that can change dynamically.

Comment: @Barmar - not really, just moving the condition to inside the event handler would suffice.

Comment: @adeneo That's essentially what `.on()` does automatically.

Comment: @Barmar - Essentially, yes! Technically it moves the event handler to a parent element, which seems unnecessary here ?

Comment: @adeneo I wonder if it has to be a parent. Could it be the element itself, by binding to a static class, and the selector argument is a dynamic class that gets added to it.

Comment: I just tried it, apparently it doesn't work.

Comment: @Barmar - Yep, won't work. The principle of delegation is really very simple -> http://jsfiddle.net/pvvYr/ , and for complex selectors it's not that efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this..

```
$('input.contact').on('click',function(){

    if( !$(this).hasClass('disabled') )
    {
        alert('---');
        $(this).addClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

Basically, when `input.contact` is clicked, check if it has the class `.disabled` - if it doesn't then trigger the `alert` and add the class `.disabled` - which in turn prevents it from triggering the second time it's clicked

Or you could have a slightly more elegant way of doing it:

```
$('.dis').on('click','input.contact:not(.disabled)',function(){
    alert('---');
    $('.contact').addClass('disabled');
});
```

Same concept.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `.disabled` element when your JS runs, so, no `.contact` is binded with `click()`.